# Error for calculating quadratic equation in C

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I wrote this program to calculating quadratic equation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    printf("ax%c + bx + c = 0", 253);
    while (1 == 1)
    {
        float a, b, c;
        printf("\na = ");
        scanf("%f", &a);
        printf("b = ");
        scanf("%f", &b);
        printf("c = ");
        scanf("%f", &c);
        if (a == 0)
        {
            if (b == 0)
                printf("\aThis equation is wrong");
            else
                printf("x = %g", -(c / b));
        }
        else
        {
            if ((b * b) == (4 * a * c))
                printf("x = %g", -(b / (2 * a)));
            else if ((b * b) > (4 * a * c))
            {
                printf("x = %g\n", ((-b + sqrt(((b * b) - (4 * a * c)))) / (2 * a)));
                printf("x = %g\n", ((-b - sqrt(((b * b) - (4 * a * c)))) / (2 * a)));
            }
            else
            {
                printf("x = %g + %gi\n", (-b / (2 * a)), (sqrt(-((b * b) - (4 * a * c))) / (2 * a)));
                printf("x = %g + %gi\n", (-b / (2 * a)), (-sqrt(-((b * b) - (4 * a * c))) / (2 * a)));
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is the error:

```
PS F:\PARSA\Programming\C> cd "f:\PARSA\Programming\C\" ; if ($?) { gcc 11.c -o 11 } ; if ($?) { .\11 }
Program '11.exe' failed to run: Access is deniedAt line:1 char:71
+ ... PARSA\Programming\C\" ; if ($?) { gcc 11.c -o 11 } ; if ($?) { .\11 }
+                                                                    ~~~~. 
At line:1 char:71
+ ... PARSA\Programming\C\" ; if ($?) { gcc 11.c -o 11 } ; if ($?) { .\11 }
+                                                                    ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```

I think that the error is for "else if" and "else" in line 26 to 35. Because when I comment both of them (just both of them), it doesn't give an error. But I don't know why! I use VS Code for IDE.

Comment: `gcc 11.c -o 11 -lm` for the math library (added `-`, `l` (lowercase L), `m`)

Comment: Those are not errors from a C compiler. Looks like PowerShell(?) error.

Answer (score 0):

The C code compiles and runs OK in my PC (VStudio 2019).
The error seems to be in what you do to compile the code at OS level:

```
cd "f:\PARSA\Programming\C\" ; if ($?) { gcc 11.c -o 11 } ; if ($?) { .\11 }
```

It looks like some error related to directory permissions, or some non-existent file.